# How to refer to other functions inside the object with Arrow function in ES6?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have this simple node module

```
module.exports = {
  func1: () => {
  }, 
  func2: () => {

  }
}
```

Now when I wanted to refer to `func1` inside `func2` I used to do `this.func1` before ES6

So now as the `this` is different in ES6. Is it correct that I have to do `module.exports.func1` inside `func2`?

So, it's going to be?

```
func2: () => {
  module.exports.func1();
}
```

Comment: why don't you declare them in separated variables? then just export them in that object

Comment: Just don't use arrow functions here. Use a method declaration instead.

Comment: `export const a = () => 'a'; export const b = () => a();`

Comment: Yes, `module.exports.func1` will work as expect. Though actually you just should use ES6 modules, have two named exports, and wouldn't need to refer to them as properties at all.

Comment: @Bergi I think that might be the wrong question to dupe as. It doesn't seem to talk about exports, just the semantics of arrow functions.

Comment: @ssube: Actually I think this question does only ask about arrow functions, and doesn't mention modules at all. You could easily replace `module.exports` with an arbitrary variable and the question wouldn't really change. If we were at [CodeReview.SE] it might be different, but that's why I've mentioned the proper module exports only in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@NaN](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4182676/nan) said in the comments, you'd be better off declaring these separately and exporting them later:

```
export function func1() {
  ...
}

export function func2() {
  ...
}

// or if you need to rename them:
export default {
  funcA: func1,
  funcB: func2
};
```